# Setting multiple javascript variables at once

Tags: javascript

I found some code which looks like this

```
var v = color.val(), sel_c = (v == '') ? "#234872" : v;
```

I'm not sure why it was written like this, but I was wondering how to read it. If we'd just have

```
var v = color.val();
```

or

```
var sel_c = (v == '') ? "#234872" : v;
```

I'd understand. But what does it mean when you separate it with commas? Its as if we were trying to set multiple variables at once or something...

Comment: Why not do an array instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [comma operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator) is used to separate multiple statements.

In the case of variable assignment it is just a way to leave out subsequent `var` keywords. Each variable is set in turn

Comment: Thanks! Didn't know the terminology to google it.

Answer (score 1):

Yap, totally valid to omit having to write `var`, `let` or `const` multiple times

```js
const a = 1,
  b = a + 1,
  c = b + 1;
console.log(a, b, c);
```

Is the same as

```
const a = 1;
const b = a + 1;
const c = b + 1;
```

just a few `var`, `let` or `const` fewer to write.

Answer (score 1):

The following is the equivalent of the code you posted:

```
var v= color.val();

var sel_c;
if(v==''){
    sel_c="#234872"
}else{
    sel_c=v;
}
```

As for why it was written as you posted it - I believe it is to conserve "space". And by space I dont mean bytes of data, but rather lines in the code editor. At least that is the reason I always get. I personally think that written like that the code is less readable, even if more compact.

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
var v = color.val(), sel_c = (v == '') ? "#234872" : v;
```

equals to:

```
var v = color.val();
var sel_c = (v == '') ? "#234872" : v;
```

The only benefit of writing it on one line is that your code will be a bit "shorter".

I personally find it ugly and hard to read.